# How to support only Lollipop on Android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, android-theme

Whenever I create a new Android project the app comes cluttered with **appcompatactivity** along with **appcompat v7 styles.**

I don't want to support devices before **Lollipop.**

I get theme rendering errors whenever I do so.

- So how do I create *clean* android apps and support only Lollipop and above?
- How to *clean* already cluttered projects?

Comment: Second question is too broad. You should be more specific ;)

Comment: "I get theme rendering errors whenever I do so" -- that represents a bug in the GUI builder of Android Studio, not your app.

Comment: "So how do I create clean android apps and support only Lollipop and above?" -- do not use the new-project and new-activity wizards in Android Studio. Start a new project by copying an existing project that does not use `appcompat-v7`, import the copy, and modify it as needed.

Comment: What dependencies are defined in your `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

> So how do I create clean android apps and support only Lollipop and
>   above?

Here's **how to support only Lollipop and above?**

You can set your **Minimum SDK version** to **API 21** when you are creating a new project in order to support Lollipop and above android version. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

You can also change it in app `build.gradle` by changing this line:

```
 defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 20
    ...
}
```

**Update: How to remove support library from project**

`AppCompatActivity` is from the `appcompat-v7` library. Principally, this offers a backport of the action bar. Since you don't want to support previous versions you don't need `AppCompatActivity`. Android Studio generates a project that uses Support Library by default, So you need to remove the support library from your project.

Here are the steps:

1- Open `build.gradle` from your project. Locate the dependencies section and remove the second line for the compatibility library

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'// This line
}
```

2- By default the app uses a theme that is available from the support library. This is not available from the core API. So we need to fix that. Open `res/values/styles.xml`. The style tag will look something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```

Change the parent to a theme that is available from the core SDK. For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```

Note that with the core SDK you must prefix the theme name with `android:style/`.

3- Finally, fix the generated activity code. Make the activity class extend `android.app.Activity`.
[from this link](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2015/04/17/removing-support-library-in-android-studio/)

**How to create clean android apps?!?!**

I think it directly depends on you and how's your code.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, how this avoids the use of `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated the answer is it correct now ?

Comment: It is better. There may be more changes than what you wrote (e.g., to code inside the activity, to menu resources), depending on what template the developer used to create the activity in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

**Give minimum Sdk version 21 for Lolipop**

Comment: Please explain, in detail, how this avoids the use of AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Lollipop is 21.

Comment: use following library      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'